# Is there a way to test HTTP Live Streaming via an iSight camera?

Tags: iphone, macos, isight, mediastreamsegmenter, http-live-streaming

I'm working on an iPhone app that will use HTTP Live Streaming. Using Apple's provided tools (particularly mediafilesegmenter), I'm able to successfully segment and serve an archived video. Now I want to test Live Streaming stuff. I don't own any sort of camcorder, I just have my iSight built-in to my Mac. Is there a way to leverage this camera to test out Live Streaming? Run iSight from the command line maybe? If so, I need a port number for mediastreamsegmenter.

Comment: How did you use mediafilesegmenter to segment the video?Any step by step tutorials available?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this out on an iPhone but I would imagine it would work:

http://autonome.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/streaming-your-isight-camera-to-the-web-with-the-video-tag/

Note that the post says you need a nightly build of VLC, this is now out of date - as long as you're using 1.0 you should be fine.

Comment: I just set it up with the latest VLC (1.0.5) and you don't even have to use the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846145/having-trouble-setting-up-mediastreamsegmenter-on-mac-os-x-10-6/4385022#4385022