# Having trouble setting up mediastreamsegmenter on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: iphone, quicktime, mediastreamsegmenter

I'm trying to use Mac OS X 10.6's mediastreamsegmenter to take the audio input of my mac and turn it into a stream that I could listen to on the iPhone.

I've read this and the related [man page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices).  But when I do something like this:

```
mediastreamsegmenter -s 3 -D -f /tmp/stream localhost:8080
```

No files appear in the 'stream' directory and when I try and use QuickTime Player X to connect to localhost:8080, no go.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13):

According to the [tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html) that describes the `mediastreamsegmenter` tool:

> This tool receives an MPEG-2 transport stream over a UDP network connection or from stdin and divides it into a series of small media segments of equal duration. It then creates an index file containing references to the individual media segments.

This means that you will need to have a UDP server running on the machine that you want to do the capture on, that is capable of pushing out the data in a MPEG2 transport stream.

I wasn't able to find anything freely available that captures from a mic input, but here is a series of steps to see a working live streaming that will stream from your iSight.

Before you start, you will need the latest version of [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

### Setup Streaming Server

1. Start VLC and select File -> Open Capture Device...
2. Select the *Capture* tab and choose iSight in the dropdown
3. Make sure the *Streaming/Saving* checkbox is enabled
4. Click the *Setting...* button and configure as in the screencap below:
   [image]
5. Click *OK*, but don't click the *Open* button just yet
6. Go to *System Preferences*, click on the *Sharing* icon and make sure *Web Sharing* is turned on.
7. Go to your home folder and in the *Sites* folder create a new folder called for example *streaming*
8. In Terminal type `mediastreamsegmenter -s 3 -D -f /Users/your-user-name/Sites/stream/ 127.0.0.1:2222` and press enter. Make sure to replace your-user-name with your short user name. If you don't know what that is, type `whoami` in the Terminal
9. In *VLC* click *Open*

If all goes well after a few seconds you should see messages like this:

```
Dec  7 2010 22:46:37.696: Finalized /Users/name/Sites/stream/fileSequence27.ts
Dec  7 2010 22:46:37.741: received 276360 written bytes 260380 skipped 15792 pat/pmt skipped 15792
Dec  7 2010 22:46:48.504: Finalized /Users/name/Sites/stream/fileSequence28.ts
Dec  7 2010 22:46:49.263: received 371112 written bytes 356636 skipped 15792 pat/pmt skipped 15792
```

### Stream

To test that everything is working:

1. Open QuickTime X
2. File -> Open URL
3. Type in `http://localhost/~name/stream/prog_index.m3u8`
4. Click *Open*

On an iPhone just open MobileSafari and go to the the same URL, e.g. `http://your.ip.address/~name/stream/prog_index.m3u8`

Comment: This worked like a charm for video -- I could not get sound to work out of the iSight preset in VLC, however. Does anyone know of a reasonably straightforward way to encode live audio similarly to the first part of this walkthrough?

Comment: Does anyone know where the streaming tools have gone?  When I go to https://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/ and click on the download link, I just get a pointer to MakeRefMovie 2.2.1.  I downloaded that, but it doesn't have any of the media programs.

Comment: Hm. When I click on the link and after logging in I get both the Make Ref Movie as well as HTTP Streaming Tools. You need to be registered Apple Developer Center person. Not sure if you need the paid membership.

Comment: just get  audio pid change to 44 when trying to do audio